# REST - How to display certain getters in javax.ws.rs.core.Response Entity

Tags: java, rest, response

I was wondering if there are any ways to annotate Entity getters in such way that the ResponseBuilder will display only the ones which have that specific annotation.

Currently I develop a REST api, and I have an entity with 6 fields, and I want to display only 3 of them on a GET request. The only solution which came into my mind is to create a wrapper over the entity class, which has getters only for the information I would like to display in the response. But before doing that, I want to know if there is another way.

This is how I currently serve the response.

```
Response.ok(device).build();
```

And this is how my entity looks like :

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@IdClass(DevicePK.class)
public class Device implements Serializable {

private static long serialVersionUID = 1l;

@Id
private String deviceId;

private String ssoId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastUpdateAt;

@Id
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Platform platform;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date associationDate;

/**
 * @return the deviceId
 */
public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

/**
 * @param deviceId the deviceId to set
 */
public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

/**
 * @return the ssoId
 */
public String getSsoId() {
    return ssoId;
}

/**
 * @param ssoId the ssoId to set
 */
public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
    this.ssoId = ssoId;
}

/**
 * @return the createdAt
 */

public Date getCreatedAtAsDate() {
    return createdAt;
}

/**
 * @param createdAt the createdAt to set
 */
public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

/**
 * @return the lastUpdateAt
 */
public String getLastUpdateAt() {
    return lastUpdateAt;
}

/**
 * @param lastUpdateAt the lastUpdateAt to set
 */
public void setLastUpdateAt(Date lastUpdateAt) {
    this.lastUpdateAt = lastUpdateAt;
}

/**
 * @return the platform
 */
public Platform getPlatform() {
    return platform;
}

/**
 * @param platform the platform to set
 */
public void setPlatform(Platform platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
}

/**
 * @return the associationDate
 */
public String getAssociationDate() {
    return associationDate;
}

/**
 * @param associationDate the associationDate to set
 */
public void setAssociationDate(Date associationDate) {
    this.associationDate = associationDate;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the annotations JsonIgnore (JSON) and XmlTransient (XML)?

Comment: Yeap, it seems that's correct, thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should annotate fields you want to exclude from response with [@XmlTransient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html).